# Monitor the performance of individual window service

Tags: windows-services, performance

I have 7 windows services. i want to monitor the performance of the individual services like the processor usage, memory usage etc.

If i use perfmon, it gives for the entire system but not the individual services. Can anyone please suggest how do i monitor the performance of individual services?

Answer (score 4):

Perfmon can monitor individual processes! Just chose process in "Add counters/Performance objects" combo. For "quick" monitoring I have found that Sysinternals (now Microsoft) Process Explorer is easy and nice. Some services give you performance information (available by sockets/files etc) that can be displayed by tools such as MRTG or Cacti.

Comment: Thanks!!
Can you please tell me what parameters i need to select in counters to find the Memory usage and CPU usage?

Comment: If you chose "Process" then you will have to "Select instance from list" (should display name of service) and counters (% Processor Time, Virtual Bytes, Handle Count etc).

Comment: if chose process in "Add counters/Performance objects", it does not give all the resource usage of my service/process. For example, it does not include Net I/O, memory usage etc. of a service.

I want to collect CPU usage, Memory usage, Net I/O, Block I/O of a service/process over certain period of time. Is there any tool for this purpose?

Comment: When you chose "Process" and your service as instance then you can add thread count, private bytes, IO Read, IO Write etc. I don't see separate Net I/O.

Answer (score 1):

To check the memory of individual services, you will have to change the service types to "Own Process". [This Gist](https://gist.github.com/rosberglinhares/239547aadfe08cf60f11025ffb3fc969) show the complete code. The central idea is trying to change the service type from the least intrusive to the most intrusive way:

```bsh
$win32Service = Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_Service -Filter "Name = '$ServiceName'" -Verbose:$false

if ($win32Service)
{
    if (!(Set-ServiceTypeToOwnProcessByCim $win32Service))
    {
        if (!(Set-ServiceTypeToOwnProcessByWindowsRegistry $win32Service))
        {
            if (Grant-FullControlRightsOnServiceRegistryKeyToCurrentUser $win32Service)
            {
                Set-ServiceTypeToOwnProcessByWindowsRegistry $win32Service | Out-Null
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    Write-Warning "[$ServiceName] Service not found"
}
```

When putting the `Set-ServiceTypeToOwnProcess.ps1` and `Enable-Privilege.ps1` files in the same folder, you can execute the script like this:

```bsh
.\Set-ServiceTypeToOwnProcess.ps1 -ServiceName 'Appinfo', 'gpsvc', 'Schedule', 'SENS', 'SessionEnv', 'wuauserv'
```