# How come I can't see Memory/CPU usage for services on windows?

Tags: windows, service, internals

On windows you can see pull up the task manager or `Get-Process` in powershell to get a  list of running processes along with their memory and cpu usage.

You can also (on windows 8 or `Get-Service` in powershell) view all running services. Yet for services you do not get any of those numbers.

From my developer point of view this always seemed a bit odd. Sure, a service requires a bunch more deployment effort and is awkward to code and debug, but otherwise it's just a program same as any other.

I'm sure there's a good reason for why services do not have those numbers, one that probably has something to do with how windows runs services. What is that reason?

Comment: To see memory usage by services, follow https://superuser.com/questions/437428/in-windows-7-is-there-a-way-to-know-how-much-memory-a-service-is-using

Comment: In defense of reopening the question: a) this is far about how services on windows work which is not really a superuser question and b) it already has a good answer. Paired with the above superuser link it is both helpful and relevant.

Comment: Agree with @George Mauer. This belongs here.

Comment: On Windows 7 and above, type "Resource Monitor" in the Windows start menu. Then click on the CPU tab, and expand Services. You can see each service separately, and how much CPU it is using

Comment: I built a script to check the memory of individual services. You can see it in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49338489/2160765).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a service host process "svchost.exe" that can start/handle multiple services. Since resource consumption is generally measured by the operating system at the process level, services that have been started by the same host process will all show up as usage by that process.

If you look in the 'services' area of the Control Panel and look for the program that starts a service, you'll find most of the Windows services all use "svchost.exe" with different parameters to start it.

Task Manager shows multiple instances of svchost.exe so it is possible to isolate a specific service to one instance of svchost.exe but you'd need to know *which* instance is serving just the service of interest.  You could use PowerShell to start the service through svchost.exe but hang onto the process ID and then add the Process ID column in Task Manager so you could see memory/CPU usage.

Comment: So does that mean that killing svchost will kill all services? Do services not run in their own process? How does all that work exactly?

Comment: Not necessarily, some services may be hosted by other processes. Plus, I counted 12 instances of svchost running on my box, some of which you probably don't want to kill. You'll need lower-level tools to find out which service run in which process, I'd start with [System Internals](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sysinternals) .

Comment: for troubleshooting purposes if we want to isolate any one service running under svchost we can do that using `sc config ServiceName type=own` http://blogs.technet.com/b/ganand/archive/2007/12/23/how-to-isolate-a-service-in-its-own-scvhost-exe.aspx

Answer (score 2):

While I haven't been able to find a way to view the memory usage of any one individual service, you can view which services are running in each instance of svchost by using `tasklist /svc` in the command line, and the memory usage of each individual svchost by looking at the Process ID.